# I'm trying to solve this error "Cannot destructure property `relatedQuery' " but no success

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I make a one to many relationship with lucid adonis and when I try to get the A data with their specific B related data (A hasMany B), it shows me this error:

> Cannot destructure property relatedQuery of 'undefined' or 'null'.

How can I solve this?

Normally I have been trying to get all data from A table with no success,
then I try to get data from B table and the A data come empty

(I use adonisjs)

```
//model code
class Device extends Model {
    properties () {
        this.hasMany('App/Models/Property');
    } 
}

class Property extends Model {
    devices() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Device');
    } 
}

// migration code
class DeviceSchema extends Schema {
    up () {
        this.create('devices', (table) => {
            table.increments();
            table.string('nome');
            table.string('photo');
            table.text('descricao');
            table.timestamps();
        });
    }

    down () {
        this.drop('devices');
    }
}

class PropertySchema extends Schema {
    up () {
        this.create('properties', (table) => {
            table.increments();
            table.string('icon');
            table.string('nome', 40);
            table.integer('deviceId')
                .unsigned()
                .notNullable()
                .references('id')
                .inTable('devices')
                .onUpdate('CASCADE')
                .onDelete('CASCADE');
            table.timestamps();
        });
    }

    down () {
        this.drop('properties')
    }
}

// controller code to get data
const Dev = await Device
    .query()
    .limit(4)
    .with('properties')
    .fetch();

console.log(Dev.toJSON())
```

I need all device data to come with their specific property data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 class Device extends Model {
     properties () {
         this.hasMany('App/Models/Property');
     } 
 }
```

You need to put the 'return' in relationship function calls:

```
    class Device extends Model {
        properties () {
      --->>    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Property');
        } 
    }
```

AdonisJs Documentation: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships